# Blazor wasm authentication with cookies session

Tags: authentication, http, blazor, session-cookies, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor wasm project and the client in which I have set up a custom AuthenticationStateProvider, now each time a user visits razor pages and GetAuthenticationStateAsync gets called, I want it to fetch the "sessionId" cookie via a get request, but since the custom provider has no HttpContext or any way to look into the cookies I want it to retrieve the cookies via the provided HttpClient.

[Custom provider class and it's private fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Lld.png)

Is there some rather obvious way that I'm missing in blazor to view the session id cookie each time a user switches razor pages and then checks the database against that session and user?

I do know the method "GetAuthenticationStateAsync" is called on each new page visit, so I assumed it was "THE" way to make this work.

All of it is of course mentioned once the user logs in and the session gets stored in the cookie.

I thought about invoking the JSRuntime in order to retrieve the cookies, but then there are many features and ways unique to blazor that are supposed to replace JavaScript, is there some way I have missed?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to access the cookie within WASM, or to access anything about the server-side session, because you're not looking at a server anymore. I think some more code examples may help, so you can show your intended usage pattern in context, like exactly where you're using your custom provider and what the greater goal is.

Comment: @binderbound The user performs a login action and after all a session cookie is created. Then there's the "GetAuthenticationStateAsync" method that is supposedly made each time the user switches between razor pages, now the related "AuthenticationStateProvider" service that is an injected singleton retrieves the user data that is "cached" (_cachedUser field as in the image) after the login, now whenever the service "forgets" the data I want it to call a get request to the server that must match the session cookie with the one stored with the user.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. Is the login action performed against a different server, and you want the session cookie from there? That would be in the context of that communication with the login server, and you need to capture the cookie in the response header, if that's the approach you're using.

Comment: @binderbound Yes that's what I did, after the login a session cookie is sent in the response header. The question is about sending a get request after each blazor page switching or other user related actions that need verification that the user is indeed who he claims to be, so the "GetAuthenticationStateAsync" will call make a request each time to see the cookie in the request headers and verify the session.